# Syntactic sugar in Web Api - how to omit [FromBody]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, syntactic-sugar

Is it possible to omit writing `[FromBody]`?

```
[HttpPost]
public string SomeMethod([FromBody]SomeModel model)
{
    return "OK";
}
```

Should I apply some global attribute? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model binding attributes in MVC 5 specify a "`BindingSource`" for each parameter on an action and can specify for each property on a controller, too. You can see specifically the code where it picks it up for the `FromBody` attribute in the [`BodyModelBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/22f1881cc641c390773783ba5a982e63a3b91464/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/BodyModelBinder.cs)

Let me say first that you should beware that as of beta6 (and I think some point in beta5), **having multiple parameters/properties with `BindingSource.Body` is not allowed**, and you will not be able to use your actions if you have multiple parameters left as the default. This might actually be desirable if you want to annotate more; my guess is that you do not.

You can see in the [`DefaultApiDescriptionProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/320507604a7045110ebf0b64f669cccddb6d9123/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer/DefaultApiDescriptionProvider.cs#L210-220) where the default source is set; unfortunately, there is no hook at this point to tie into, and the method itself is private and not virtual; you'll need to re-implement the entire class.

Once you have, though, it's rather easy to register it in your `ConfigureServices` to use it instead:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IApiDescriptionProvider, YourApiDescriptionProvider>());
```

You can see [the default being registered in the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/951a1d087994a5a41de2a3eba7652794c0fca95e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L187), too.

Comment: the question is about web api though.. not mvc.

Comment: WebApi is merged with MVC 6 - they are no longer separate.

Answer (score 0):

probably more than one way to achieve this.. here is one way: a custom ActionValueBinder..

1. Write a custom class to extend from `DefaultActionValueBinder`.

   public class FromBodyParameterBindingActionValueBinder : DefaultActionValueBinder
2. Override the GetParameterBinding method.

   ```
   protected override HttpParameterBinding 
             GetParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
   {
       return parameter.ActionDescriptor.SupportedHttpMethods.Contains(HttpMethod.Post)
       ||  parameter.ActionDescriptor.SupportedHttpMethods.Contains(HttpMethod.Put) ?
              parameter.BindWithAttribute(new FromBodyAttribute()) : 
              base.GetParameterBinding(parameter);
   }
   ```

basically what we're saying is that if the Web API system gets a POST or PUT call, make FromBody as the default parameter binding methodology.

3. Once we have our custom binder, register it globally.

   GlobalConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(IActionValueBinder), new FromBodyParameterBindingActionValueBinder());

what this does is that for every POST/PUT request, Web API will try to create the model from the request Body. you don't need to provide the `[FromBody]` attribute explicitly.

---

having said that, you need to understand the implications of what you're requesting..

Web API has some default rules on model binding. (can be changed)

1. primitive action parameters are first, looked into the query string
2. then request body.
3. complex action parameters are first, looked into the request body.
4. then query string.

also, web api can only read the first `[FromBody]` action parameter.. subsequent parameters cannot be read from the body.

the reason i am enumerating the above rules, is so that you're aware of the behavior when you expect some model to be created, but web api does not seem to create it from the body.

for me, explicitly providing `[FromBody]` is a lot more readable and predictable.. but if you're in full control of your APIs in terms of Http Verbs and expect all requests to be via the Body, it is a perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: It looks like from your use of `GlobalConfiguration` and `DefaultActionValueBinder` you're using MVC 5, not MVC 6.

Comment: can somebody please explain the downvote on the answer.. glad to learn the reason for it.